# Можно ли в if проверить return от функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Я написал функцию с `х` значением, которое может принимать либо 1, либо 2. И в зависимости от `х` я создал внутри этой функции ещё одну функцию, в которой он проверяет значение `х`. Когда `х==1`, он делает `return 1`, а когда `х==2` - то `return 0`.
Вопрос: я хочу проверить функцию, например, если функция равна 1, то сделай что-то, иначе - сделай что-то другое...

```
import random

def coin(x=random.randint(1,2)):
    if x == 1 :
        print('Head')
    else:
        print('Tail')

    def flip():
        a=None
        if x == 1:
            a=1
        elif x == 2:
            a=0

    flip()
```

типа как проверить `return`, например, что-то такое:

if coin() == 1:
print(+)

Или подскажите, как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто верните значение из `coin` и из `flip`:

```
import random

def coin():
    x = random.randint(1, 2)
    if x == 1:
        print('Head')
    else:
        print('Tail')

    def flip():
        a = None
        if x == 1:
            a = 1
        elif x == 2:
            a = 0

        return a

    return flip()


for i in range(10):
    if coin() == 1:
        print('coin == 1')
```

Answer (score 2):

Народ! Если мне глаза не изменяют, то  функцию

```
   def flip():
        a = None
        if x == 1:
            a = 1
        elif x == 2:
            a = 0
```

можно записать короче:

```
def flip():
    return x%2
```

ну или другой вариант:

```
def flip():
    return 0 if x==2 else 1
```

Answer (score 0):

На python не пишу, но наверное надо добавить "return a" в функцию flip

```
def flip():
    a=None
    if x == 1:
        a=1
    elif x == 2:
        a=0
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

если значений, которые может принимать `x` много, то чтобы не городить простыню из if/elif/else, можно воспользоваться таким приемом, где ключи из `DX` это условия из if/elif, а None соответствует else

```
import random
DX = {1: 1, 2: 0, 10: 3, 50: 2, None: -1, }

def coin():
    x = random.randint(1, 100)
    # return DX.get(x, -1)
    try: return DX[x]
    except KeyError: return DX[None]
```